# prove this algebra question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me with this linear algebra problem? Thank you...

> The real roots of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0,\ a<0$ are $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Given that $\beta<\alpha<-2$, show that $4a+2|b| + c < 0$.

Comment: Please type the question in. There is help available on formatting mathematics – see the help menu.

Comment: well I've attatched an image

Comment: @cired1977 The image quality is very poor.  I've tried transcribing it, did you write that $a<0$, or did you mean $\alpha<0$ to be explicitly stated?

Comment: Hint: start with $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and see what can be said about $f(-2)$?

Comment: Solve the equation using the quadratic equation to figure out what alpha and beta are in terms of a and b.   See what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

$ax^2+bx+c=0$

$x=\frac {-b\pm \sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a} $

So $\alpha = \frac {-b+\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and $\beta = \frac {-b- \sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

and

$ \frac {-b-\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}< \frac {-b+ \sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a} < -2$

Can we use that?

Answer (score 2):

Since $a<0$, the quadratic function, $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is concave, the quadratic function attains maximum value at $\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$. The function increases from $-\infty$ to $\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$ and then decreases.

In particular, if $x > \alpha$, then $f(x)<f(\alpha)=0$

We are told that $\alpha<-2$

Hence $f(-2)<0$ and $f(2)<0$.

$$f(-2)=4a-2b+c<0$$
$$f(2)=4a+2b+c <0$$
Hence,
$$4a+2|b|+c<0$$